# XAMPP : Problem killing PID 11308 Check that you have the proper privileges.... Apache and mysql can't stop

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

**Apache  Error**

Problem killing PID 11308
Check that you have the proper privilege

**MYSQL**

There may be an error, return code: 40286176 -

Here's a screenshot that shows the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZGPP.png

Answer (score 1):

Arjun,

could you share more info like:

the 'netstat' what's application has been running or not

and go to windows service to search any 'apache' or 'mysql' has been running or not

please kill it if you found in the window service.

And please try download the latest version if it is possible:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.4.3/